# Search any element from a list in another list in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a column called `LocationsManaged` specifying the `location(s)` which a person manages. e.g. `Delhi,Kanpur,Patna` for manager 1, `Ajmer,Chandigarh,Jaipur` for `manager2` and `Bhopal,Nagpur,Raipur` for `manager3`. In another column called `LocationsApplicable`, I have the list of locations for which a scheme is applicable e.g. `Chandigarh,Delhi,Jaipur,Kanpur`. So, in this case, the scheme is applicable to `Manager 1` & `Manager2`, but not `Manager 3`. Now I want to find out (preferably using a single non-nested query) the list of managers for whom the scheme is applicable. Is it possible in `MySQL` ?

Comment: Yes. See normalisation

Comment: or use `find_in_set()`, which seems to exist just because of poorly thought through implementations like this

Answer (score 0):

Normalization is almost always the best option.

That being said, if your table is small you can use [`find_in_set`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) as well.

Comment: Appreciate normalisation, but customer changed the specs too late. Anyway, I doubt if find_in_set will work. What it does is "SELECT FIND_IN_SET('b','a,b,c,d');" What I need is "SELECT somefunction('b,x,t','a,b,c,d');" Here either "b" or "x" or "t" is found in the string "a,b,c,d", then it should show true. If none of the 3 is found, then false. Possible ?